# AWS EC2 is blocking all HTTP ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

I have multiple websites on one EC2 instance, which were working perfectly on both HTTP and HTTPS until this morning. I have jenkins installed as well, on port 8080.

Strangely, no changes were made, but now all HTTP ports are blocked, 80, 443 and 8080.
I've allowed all traffic from all sources currently, and it still blocks those ports.

[image: AWS Security Group Definition]

SSH port is working, and when I ssh and test using `wget` such as

`wget -O - http://localhost` - works

`wget -O - http://private-ip` - works

`wget -O - http://public-ip` - no requests

`wget -O - http://my-domain` - no requests

More over, if I run nginx or some other http server on some port other than `80`, `443`, `8080`, I'm receiving requests from both public-ip and my-domain.

ufw is disabled and iptables are empty

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive


sudo iptables -t nat -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                    
    
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                    
    
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                                    
    
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination   


wget -O - http://localhost
--2020-11-11 16:08:54--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

wget -O - http://private-ip
--2020-11-11 16:09:19--  http://private-ip/
Connecting to private-ip:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

wget -O - http://public-ip
--2020-11-11 16:10:11--  http://public-ip/
Connecting to public-ip:80...
```

HTTP Server on port 81 works.

[image: HTTP server on port 81 works]

Comment: Have you validated from the console that the public IP address is correct?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams yes, when I set up http server on port other than 80, 443, 8080 it works. Just those ports are somehow blocked.

Comment: Are the web server processes that should be listening on 80, 443, and 8080 actually up & running? Do they have any logs that help diagnose things?

Comment: @jarmond yes, they are up and running. In case of nginx, I've been checking access.log, but no requests are made. If I test using other http server, like on last image example, SimpleHttpServer, it also does not receive any requests on port 80. But If I set it to listen on port 81, everything works fine (see last image)

Comment: I'd hate to simply say "reboot" because you'll lose a potentially valuable problem diagnosis. I'd be tempted to go the packet capture route at both client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. Since WP was hosted on instance, it got some malicious scripts, and some other sites have reported us to ec2-abuse, so AWS has blocked those ports.

Not sure how it was not stated somewhere on AWS Console? Seems like that info is available only if client has paid support.